# Beamer section/subsection links do not work with impressive

Tags: beamer, links

I am currently creating a presentation for my university with Beamer. I decided to use the [`Impressive`](http://impressive.sourceforge.net/) script mainly because I wanted a clock counter and the fade-in-fade-out effect impressive provides when switching slides.

However, I observe that when using impressive, the header links (for section/subsection) no longer work. This is because when I click the mouse to the link, impressive intercepts the click and changes slide to next slide instead of the linked one.

Is there any possible work-around about this? I am running impressive using the command:

```
impressive.py -L margin=16,time=BL --fontsize 20 --transition Crossfade presentation.pdf &
```

Comment: Hyperlinks should work [since `Impressive` version 0.10.1](http://impressive.sourceforge.net/news.php). However, according to [the documentation](http://impressive.sourceforge.net/manual.php), there are a few requirements, the most important probably being that you have [`pdftk`](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) installed. Anyway, this is really more a bug-report than a TeX-related question, so it's probably best to contact the `Impressive` author Martin Fiedler <martin.fiedler@gmx.net>.

Comment: Indeed, I have read the same thing in this page. However, I already have pdftk installed. Maybe it has something to do with how I generate the PDF file? Anyway, I will follow your suggestion and mail the author (I hope he replies :-) ).  Any other suggestions are fixing this are more than welcome though :)

Thanks,